# Two local branches being tracked by two different remote repos

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently working on a project where I had to branch off of `master`, make a bunch of changes locally and 'go-live' with a testing environment that is pushed to a particular remote repo, as follows:

```
git push origin site-testing
```

pushes to `site-testing` branch in the following repo:

```
user-name@testing.com:/path/to/root-dir-containing-.git
```

Now I need to cherry pick changes from the `site-testing` branch on to the `master` branch.

The catch is, when I `git push origin master`, I would like these changes to be pushed to a totally different remote repo.

So the desired outcome is:

```
git push origin master
```

pushes `master` to the following repo:

```
user-name@aws-live-domain.com:/path/to/root-dir-containing-.git
```

and **not** `master` on `testing.com`..

Is this possible? I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Watch out: the syntax for `git push` is `git push <remote> <branch>`, not just `git push <branch>`. If you write a branch name there, Git will treat it as the name of a remote. I'll add an answer too.

Comment: im not sure I follow, can you elaborate?

Comment: I was referring to your example where you wrote `git push site-testing`. You would need `git push <remote> site-testing`, or `git push <url> site-testing`, to have this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another origin and push to it, as follows:

```
git remote add origin1 https://aws-live-domain.com/user-name/<path/to/root-dir-containing->.git
git push origin1 master
```

Comment: Didn't work, getting an error `fatal: No such remote 'origin1'`

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one remote.  This lets you do what you want.

The general syntax for using `git push` is:

`git push remote branch`

which you will often see, e.g., as `git push origin master`.  The `origin` part is the name of a *remote* and the second part is a branch name (well, it's actually more complicated, but let's just go with "branch name" here :-) ).

Remember that a *remote* in Git is just a short name for another Git repository at some other URL.  Typically, a Git repository comes with one remote, named `origin`, pre-made, because `git clone` sets up one remote for you, and the name it uses by default is `origin`.

To add another, different, remote, run `git remote add`, e.g.:

```
git remote add xyzzy ssh://user-name@testing.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Now `xyzzy` is the name of a second remote, that refers to a Git repository on `testing.com`, accessed via `ssh user-name@testing.com`, living in `path/to/repo.git` on that system.  You can now `git push xyzzy branch`.

#### But wait, there's more!

Each branch may have one (and only one) *upstream* setting.  The upstream of a branch is actually a pair of items: it's the name of the remote, plus a branch-name.  This pair of items is also what your Git uses to *remember* that branch *as seen on that remote* the last time *your* Git actually *conversed* with that other Git.

Hence, if you have a branch `plugh-test` that should normally push to remote `xyzzy`, you can do:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=xyzzy/plugh-test plugh-test
```

Now your branch `plugh-test` remembers that its upstream is `xyzzy/plugh-test`, which is your own Git's memory of `plugh-test` as seen on remote `xyzzy`.

If your `push.default` setting is `simple` (as it is by default in Git 2.0 or later), and you are *on* branch `plugh-test`, you can just run:

```
git push
```

because your Git will look up your *current branch*'s remote, and use that as the default *remote* argument, when pushing the current branch, which is the default *branch* argument.

Note, though, that if you accidentally run:

```
git push colossal-cave
```

thinking that this will push the *branch* `colossal-cave`, it won't: the positional argument here is always a *remote*, not a branch.

[(`xyzzy` and `plugh` are magic verbs from Colossal Cave Adventure.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure)

Comment: Thank you for the wealth of knowledge